# How could I select specific elements from a array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Using this characters array, print to the console every character which name begins with ‘M’. Don’t use any kind of loop, yet. Just print to console each name separately.

```
        var filmCharacters =[

        ['Vito', 'Michael', 'Sonny', 'Freddo'],

        ['Mia', 'Vincent', 'Jules', 'Butch'], 

        ['Bella', 'Edward', 'Jacob', 'Carlisle'],

        ['James', 'M', 'Moneypenny', 'Felix']

];
```

Comment: you will need a loop of some kind

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a homework completion service. We'll help people who have tried to complete tasks (of whatever origin), but there should be some indication of research having been done, and attempts having been made.

Comment: @HereticMonkey How do you know that it is Homework?

Comment: I apologize, but i just started now learning and only have seen ".pop/.push/.split and .join" to work with arrays.

Comment: @Shrey The tone and structure of the question's language; everything is in the imperative toward the reader: "print to the console", "Don't use any kind of loop". Normal people don't ask questions of others using commands like that. It's more often found in educational settings.

Comment: @HereticMonkey I'll remember that . . . Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using the [reduce](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_reduce.asp) on the outer array and then [filtering](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_filter.asp) the inner array.

After filtering you can join them back together with the current values

```js
> filmCharacters.reduce((acc, curr) => [...acc, ...curr.filter(x => x.startsWith('M'))], [])
[ 'Michael', 'Mia', 'M', 'Moneypenny' ]
```

Comment: Answers which explain code are less often downvoted than those which don't.

Comment: And people get rep for answering no-effort questions which are duplicates of hundreds of other questions, therefore reducing the quality of the entire platform. Seems like we can't have nice things either way.

Comment: @HereticMonkey this question hasn't been marked for duplication yet.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I figured we were just complaining about random things on the site... My bad.